# Question about the proof that $A = B \implies \{A, B\} = \{A \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, first-order-logic

I'm trying to do it as a 100% explicit proof, and I have a couple of questions. Here's the proof:

Suppose $A,B$ are sets, and suppose $A=B$, and suppose $\gamma \neq \varnothing$ and $\gamma \in \{A,B\}$.

$\implies \gamma = A \lor \gamma = B$

$\gamma = B \iff \gamma = A$

$\implies \gamma = A \lor \gamma = A$

$\implies \gamma = A$

$\therefore\gamma \in \{A\}$

Suppose instead $\gamma \in \{A\}$.

$\implies \gamma = A \lor \gamma = \varnothing$

$\gamma \neq \varnothing$

$\implies \gamma = A$

$\implies \gamma = A \lor \gamma = A$

$\gamma = A \iff \gamma = B$

$\implies \gamma  = A \lor \gamma = B$

$\therefore \gamma \in  \{A,B\}$

$\therefore A = B \implies \{A,B\} = \{A \}$

Some questions about the proof:

1. Is it correct?
2. My main problem is that although I'm trying to do a 100% explicit proof, I'm unable to determine when I'm actually stating a tautology which doesn't advance the proof in any way. For example, it seems to me that normally $A = B$ directly implies $\{A,B\} = \{A,A\}$, but at the same time, it feels to me like this doesn't necessarily follow, since I was able to write a step-by-step transformation of the one into the other. What exactly are the assumptions necessary to be able to get a direct implication from $A=B$ to $\{A,B\} = \{A,A\}$? Is it a syntactical thing?
3. Under what syntactical and first-order assumptions does $\gamma \in \{A,B\}$ mean (or imply?) $\gamma = A \lor \gamma = B$? It has been suggested in the comments that actually, any disjunction is infinitely long, but under what assumptions is this the case?

Any suggestions, reading recommendations, or answers, are very highly appreciated!

Comment: The condition $\gamma \ne \emptyset$ is superfluous

Comment: Under what assumptions does $\gamma\in\{A,B\}$ mean $\gamma = A\vee \gamma = B$... This is true always.  No assumptions are needed, that is merely what the notation means.  As for assuming $\gamma \neq \emptyset$... that is entirely unnecessary.  Do not forget that $\{\emptyset\}$ is just as valid a set as any other.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but then, isn't it the case that $\gamma \in \{A\} \iff \gamma = A$ is false, since $\gamma$ could be equal to $\varnothing$?

Comment: As for $\gamma \in \{A\}\implies \gamma = A\vee \gamma = \emptyset$... I mean... yes, that's true however it is far simpler to write $\gamma\in \{A\}\iff \gamma = A$.  There is no need for the $\vee \gamma = \emptyset$ here... just like how $x^2=9$ implies that $x=3\vee x=-3\vee x=12374879487379$ is true... the reverse implication is not... since $12374879487379^2\neq 9$.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing yourself with regards to what it means for the emptyset to be *an element of* another set which only happens some of the time... and are conflating that with the fact that the emptyset is always a *subset of* any other set.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh that's an important distinction! thank you very much!

Comment: @JMoravitz another question, (thank you very much for the answers already given!) but it seems to me that $x^2 = 9 \implies x=3 \lor x=-3 \lor 582579...$ isn't necessarily always true, depending on syntactical and first-order assumptions, no? Otherwise, for example, a computer could not process that sentence

Comment: Perhaps I shorthanded the expression too much and assumed context was obvious....  Given the universe of consideration to be the real numbers and given the common meanings of multiplication and other standard arithmetical notations... the statement that $x^2=9$ does indeed imply that $x$ takes a value equal to one of $3,-3,3838478383$.  Now... We as experienced mathematicians know that in fact we could have narrowed it down further... to say that $x$ takes a value equal to one of $3,-3$ and that additional nonsense number was not actually possible... but that doesn't change the truth

Comment: If you want to "secure your proof", why don't you state explicitly which axiom you are using at each step?

Comment: To emphasize again... $x^2=9\iff x\in \{3,-3\}\color{red}{\implies} x\in\{3,-3,12389479\}$ noting the red $\color{red}{\implies}$ is a one-way implication and the reverse implication is false.  I am with this example trying to emphasize that $\gamma\in\{A\}\iff \gamma = A\color{red}{\implies}\gamma = A\vee \gamma = \emptyset$, this same red $\color{red}{\implies}$ and the $\vee \gamma = \emptyset$ is wholly unnecessary

Comment: As for "*Any disjunction is infinitely long*"...  Any statement $P$ will imply a disjunction involving that statement...  that is... $P\implies P\vee Q$... and you can extend this with however many additional statements you wish... $P\implies P\vee A_1\vee A_2\vee A_3\vee \dots$  however the point is to not confuse the symbol $\implies$ which is a one way implication with the symbol $\iff$ which is a bi-implication.  The point is, don't bring in information which is unnecessary and irrelevant when able.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I was hoping someone could give me references on relevant axioms, since it is the first time I ask myself these questions! I only know ZFC, but it seems explicitly stating the axioms is here a question of first-order logic. I will however follow this recommendation, thanks!

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you very much for your answers, I'll mull it over!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=B$, then $\{A,B\}=\{A\}$ which is almost not necessary to be proved.

- If what you chose is naive set theory, then the conclusion conclude clearly from the naive definition of sets. In Cantor's words, a set is a gathering together into a whole of *definite, distinct* objects of our perception or our thought. This means that sets have three property: (1) elements are definite; (2) elements are distinct; (3) elements have no orders.
- If what you chose is axiomatic set theory, then the conclusion conclude easily from Axiom of Extension: For any sets $x,y$, if for any sets $z$ we have $z\in x$ if and only if $z\in y$ then $x=y$, i.e., $\forall x,y(\forall z(z\in x\leftrightarrow z\in y)\to x=y))$.

---

By the way, if you still want to check whether your proof method is right or not, the following may be a reference.

*Proof* 1. This because
$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
x\in\{A,B\}&\iff&x=A~\text{or}~x=B&\\
&\iff&x=A~\text{or}~x=A&\text{by}~A=B\\
&\iff&x=A&\text{by}~(\varphi\vee\varphi)\leftrightarrow\varphi\\
&\iff&x\in\{A\}.&
\end{array}
$$

**Remark.** Although Proof 1 is also right, but it's a detour and not necessary since $\{A,A\}=\{A\}$ is obvious. I think what you focused is not how to prove it in a clear and neat way but whether your own proof method is right or not.

---

If a proof is necessary, I think the following is better.

*Proof* 2. Suppose $A=B$. Then $\{A,B\}=\{A,A\}=\{A\}$ as desired.

Comment: thank you so much for the explicit proof! I didn't know you could do it without splitting the implication! thanks!